# c# and google spreadsheet row height, merging cells

Tags: c#, gdata, google-sheets-api

I am using gdata version 2.1. I guess version 3.0 is not out yet. My question is:
Is there a way to set row height or merge cells in google spreadsheets using c# and gdata? 
Thank you all..

Answer (score 0):

Version 2.1 of the .NET client library implements version 3 of the Spreadsheets API, which doesn't support setting row height or merging cells.

For more details about the API features, check the documentation: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/